# How to split a SQL Select query into two Model C# with Dapper ORM

Tags: c#, orm, mapping, dapper

[image: Team select data with pagination info.]

I want to split data into two separate models with DAPPER ORM in C#, From `TeamId` to `Location` between a column in one model and `RowNumber` to `PageCount` into another sperate model.

Comment: you can make 2 different query for each model

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to simulate would be an object such as:

```
public class Team
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
     public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

You can actually achieve this with Dapper up to seven objects, basically what you would do in your SQL would be:

```
public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams() => dbConnection.Query<Team, Supervisor, Location, Team>(query, 
(team, supervisor, location, team) => 
{
   team.Supervisor = supervisor,
   team.Location = location,
   return team;  
});
```

You can find documentation on their multi object mapping [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dapper%20multimapping%20object&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  I should denote it splits on Id unless specified and the order the objects appear in query result matter.