# How to return multiple results from stored procedure using dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, dapper

I have two tables Attributes and Types. Both I need to return at the same time using stored procedure in Dapper.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870494/how-to-split-a-sql-select-query-into-two-model-c-sharp-with-dapper-orm it can be help

Comment: I suggest you return the result as <dynamic>

Answer (score 0):

You perform a `QueryMultiple`:

```
string sql = "Invoice_Select";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        var invoice = multi.Read<Invoice>().First();
        var invoiceItems = multi.Read<InvoiceItem>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Reference:

- https://dappertutorial.net/querymultiple
- https://dappertutorial.net/stored-procedure

Comment: Thanks. How can I make QueryMultiple as generic

Comment: "How can I make QueryMultiple as generic", what do you mean Hardik?

Comment: Like I want to use QueryMultiple at various places. So I have to do the above thing again and again. So I wanted a generic code. For example:
For returning data from store procedure I have a generic code as:

 public static IEnumerable<T> ReturnList<T>(string procedureName, DynamicParameters param = null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                return sqlCon.Query<T>(procedureName, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }

        }

Comment: So why in this case you don't simply create your extension methods "ReturnQueryMultiple" which call the QueryMultiple but with your setting already predefined or thing you want generic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var results = conn.QueryMultiple(@"
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.Users; 
    SELECT Id, CompanyName FROM dbo.Companies
");
var users = results.Read<User>();            
var companies = results.Read<Company>();
```